# How do I activate Google Custom Search?

Tags: 7, search

I've just installed the [Google Custom Search Module](http://drupal.org/project/gss).

I've activated the module and inserted the API. The search is is till not working.

Something I'm missing?

Note: I've realized I need the paid version. is there a free Google Custom Search, free option?

Comment: "The search is not working" doesn't really give us much to go on...could you list in detail the steps you've taken so far, what you've done to try debugging, etc (it'll save anyone trying to help you trying things that are pointless since you've already tried them). Also check the logs and see if there are any errors, and make sure you've read the module's README file completely, and followed all instructions in there

Comment: I've realized I need the paid version. is there a free Google Custom Search, free option?

Comment: You'd need to ask Google really...

Comment: how about its alternative module : http://drupal.org/project/google_cse?

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in `README.txt` file:

```
*** About Google Site Search module
---------------------------------------
This requires "Site Search Edition" (paid version of Google's Custom Search).
```

You need to have a paid Google Site Search engine, so you can receive results in custom format (e.g. XML).

If you've free version, check the alternatives modules such as: [Google Search Appliance](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_appliance) or [Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_cse). Or use alternative services such as [Yahoo YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (e.g. [YQL Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/yql_views_query)).

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still searching for a free solution - you could try the [Simple Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_gse_search) module. I have been using these on production sites without any issues.

> Provides integration with [Google's Custom Search Engine](https://google.com/cse).

**Note:** I am one of the maintainers of the module. Please feel free to report any issues in the issue queue.